# Colocar swedll32.dll em uma aplicação Web

Tags: aplicação-web

Preciso criar uma solução para um cliente de uma aplicação web que produza cálculos da posição dos planetas.

Fui indicado a utilizar essa biblioteca swedll32.dll , e fiz alguns testes e funciona muito bem em Delphi 7.

O problema é que preciso publicar em uma aplicação web e não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar. Tentei utilizando .net

Qual a solução que preciso:

- Uma aplicação web (qualquer linguagem) que faça acesso a essa dll e faça os cálculos
- Uma opção de hospedagem dessa aplicação

Para mais detalhes da aplicação seguem links dos códigos de exemplo e documentação.

http://www.astro.com/swisseph/swephinfo_e.htm

http://www.astro.com/ftp/swisseph/programs/

Vou colocar um trecho de código em delphi bem simples para se entender o que preciso.

Muito grato =)

---

```
function swe_julday(year     : integer;
                    month      : integer;
                    day        : integer;
                    hour       : double;
                    gregflag   : integer
) : double; stdcall; far; external 'swedll32.dll' name '_swe_julday@24';

function swe_calc(tjd          : double;    {Julian day number}
                   ipl         : Integer;   {planet number}
                   iflag       : Longint;   {flag bits}
                   var xx      : double;    {first of 6 doubles}
                   sErr        : PChar      {Error-String}
): Longint; stdcall; far; external 'swedll32.dll' name '_swe_calc@24';


function PegaPosicaoDoPlaneta() : string;
var
  tjd,
  dhour,
  tjdet : double;

  planet_number : integer

  iday, imonth, iyear : integer;
  iflag, rflag : Longint;
  xx    : Array[0..5] of double;
  serr :  Array[0..255] of Char;
  sjul: String[30];

  resultado : string;
begin

  iday := 1;
  imonth := 1;
  iyear := 2016;

  ihour := 11;
  imin := 59;
  isec := 00;
  dhour := ihour + imin / 60.0 + isec / 3600.0;

  tjd := swe_julday(iyear, imonth, iday, dhour, 1);

  planet_number := 0;

  iflag := 0;
  rflag := swe_calc(tjd, planet_number, iflag, xx[0], serr);

  Str(xx[0]:16:10,  sjul);

  resultado := 'Planeta ' +  IntToStr(planet_number) + ' na posicao = ' +  sjul;
  result := resultado;
end;
```

Comment: Achei o código-fonte dele em C: http://www.astro.com/ftp/swisseph/src/ - No entanto, é um código bem complexo e difícil de se entender.